# how to use unordered map in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, header, unordered-map

I am writing a program that uses unordered map. after some research prior to this, I know that to use unordered map, first we need to put  header. but It didn't worked. thanks in advance for any tips. and oh ya this is the error message

```
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
umap.cpp: In function 'int main()':
umap.cpp:21:2: error: 'unordered_map' was not declared in this scope
  unordered_map<string, int> siswa;
  ^
umap.cpp:21:22: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
  unordered_map<string, int> siswa;
                      ^
umap.cpp:21:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
  unordered_map<string, int> siswa;
                        ^
umap.cpp:24:2: error: 'siswa' was not declared in this scope
  siswa["saleh"]=90;
  ^
```

AND here's the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std;

void cari(string key){

    if(siswa.find(key)==siswa.end())
        cout<<siswa[key]<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"n/a"<<endl;
}


int main(){


    unordered_map<string, int> siswa;


    siswa["saleh"]=90;
    siswa["mutiara"]=85;
    siswa["icam"]=70;

    int t;
    cin>>t;
    string key;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){

        getline(cin,key);
        cari(key);
    }
}
```

btw, sorry for my messy grammar :v

Comment: First, ```cout<<siswa[key]<<endl;``` in your cari function is not decleare in this scope because it's not a global variable. You have to give the unordered_map to your function

Comment: Don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: What compiler do you use and what compiler flags do you pass? Also, [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Your first error is incomplete and is a hint for the others. Have you enabled C++11?

Comment: You need to compile with support for at least `c++11`.  Also. please get rid of [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: you didnt `#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

The scope error pertains to your unordered map not being accessible to the function `cari` within its scope, for which you can include an unordered map of corresponding data types as a parameter:

```cpp
void cari(string key, unordered_map<string,int> x)
{
  if(x.find(key)==x.(end))
   cout<<x[key]<<"\n";
  else
   cout<<"n/a"<<"\n";
}
```

Other points to take note of:

- As already addressed in the comments, avoid use of `<bits/stdc++.h>`. Its been mentioned thousand of times but its recurring usage is not a suprise since the newcomers in CP are misguided or have an inclination to use it with the most common reason being to save time writing the headers contained in the STL. But then you can always use a pre-written template when necessary. Additionally, most of the problems don't involve more than four headers so its not much of a hassle writing them within the contest duration either. 
  The use of this header is discouraged primarily because it includes the whole STL family of headers, which makes the program redundant and in turn slow to compile as well. Moreover, although its supported in online-judges/compilers, its not supported in most IDEs (eg: Visual Studio) and compilers. Its usage is highly discouraged in production code as well, so take it as a point to avoid using it.
- Use `std::string` or include `<cstring>`/`<string.h>` header. Note that if you don't declare namespace `std` (use of which again is considered as a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)), you'll have to use `std::` as a prefix wherever required such as for `cin`, `cout`, `string` and `unordered_map` here. The parameters of the function would then look like:

```cpp
void cari(std::string key, std::unordered_map<std::string,int> x)
```

- Use `\n` instead of `endl` as the later invokes an unnecessary call to `std::flush()`.
- `while(t--)` is a better alternative than the for loop used to iterate over `t` (or the test cases I presume) as its shorter and discards use of an extra loop variable.

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh Consider accepting the answer (tapping the tick mark just below the votes) if it helps!